# Know from which pcap filter my packet came

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap

I'm trying to use libpcap to sniff some "network interfaces" (loopback included).

In my example application, I have packets coming from the loopback in the ports 1234, 1235 and 1236. I found already a way to make libpcap filter only packets coming from these addresses, using libpcap_setfilter(): my goal was to forward these packets accordingly to the address/port from which they came (for example, packets coming from 127.0.0.1/1234 could go through the eth0 interface; packets coming from 127.0.0.1/1235 could be forwarded through the eth1; and the ones coming from 127.0.0.1/1236 could be forwarded though the eth2).

My question is: is there any way to know from exactly what port these packets came without having to look at their content? Can I, for example, set many filters and somehow know from what filter was the one who filtered my packet?

I've already read a lot of the documentation and of tutorials, but none seemed useful so far. I also will be ok if the answer is "it is not possible".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capture mechanisms atop which libpcap runs support only one filter, so libpcap has no APIs to set multiple filters.

You could, however, open multiple `pcap_t`'s for the same network interface and apply different filters to them.  Reading from multiple `pcap_t`'s, however, is potentially platform-dependent.  I infer from the "eth0", "eth1", and "eth2" that this is Linux, so you should be able to use `select()` or `poll()` or... on the return values from `pcap_get_selectable_fd()` on the `pcap_t`'s and, if `select()` or `poll()` or... says a given descriptor is readable, call `pcap_dispatch()` on the corresponding `pcap_t` to process packets for that `pcap_t`.